# In a Django view, how do I format a date like in a template?

Tags: django, date

If I have a [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object, and I render it in a Django template like this:

```
{{ foobar }}
```

Then Django will format it to look pretty:

```
July 18, 2019, midnight
```

How to do the same thing inside a Django view in Python code? I'm imagining a function named `render_date` in this example:

```
def example_view(request):
    # ...
    example = "Date is: " + render_date(foo_date)
```

I would like it to render exactly the same way as it would in the template. How do I do this?

It should respect the settings `DATE_FORMAT`, `DATETIME_FORMAT`, `TIME_FORMAT`, `SHORT_DATE_FORMAT` and `USE_L10N`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how:

```
from django.utils.formats import date_format, time_format

example = "Date is: "     + date_format(foo_date) # datetime.date
example = "Datetime is: " + date_format(foo_datetime, 'DATETIME_FORMAT') # datetime.datetime
example = "Time is: "     + time_format(foo_time) # datetime.time
```